# Persistent CSS class change on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I want to let the readers of my HTML page adjust the font size. I can make a simple button and an onlick event via javascript that will change the font-size property in the corresponding css file - say change `body { font-size: 10px;}` to `body { font-size: 12px;}`.

However such changes do not persist upon page reload, or when the user moves to a different page. What would be the simplest solution to save the font-size under some kind of variable that would last until the browser is closed? Are cookies the only way to do this (meaning, is there a way to do the same thing without having the user download anything?).

Any suggestion/reference is much appreciated.

Comment: you could persist it with a cookie or a storage system.

Comment: There are many options for storage systems which I would suggest using. There is session storage, local storage (up to 5mb), cookies, and you could even use a database system with ajax! Your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Html 5 storage mechanisms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).  Quick rundown:  localStorage lasts until it is cleared for the web-page, and sessionStorage only lasts until the browser is closed.

Both store data client-side.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't fix the font size in the first place by specifying it in pixels, i.e. if you use:

```
body { font-size: small;}
```

(or maybe better medium rather than small for best results for people with poor eyesight) instead of `body { font-size: 10px;}`, then you won't need to provide such a facility in the first place. The user will be able to to use the browser's Text-only Zoom facility to enlarge the text - they are used to doing that - and that lasts for as long as they stay on the site in the same window. Many users with permanent zoom requirements will probably have their own stylesheet as well.

Providing one's own zoom facility is somewhat outdated now, it dates from the days when browsers didn't handle it so well.

It's primarily Internet Explorer that doesn't allow users to enlarge the text if it's set in px units, which is why you need to set it as small or medium font size - Firefox and some others overrule even px units.

Comment: that's a good point, however setting a fixed value in px (or ft in my case) allows me to have more control over the display of my page on various devices. having an initial value for the font size also allows me to use the "em" property more easily for creating graphics exclusively out of divs, for example, which requires precise alignments etc. but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

That is: you want to share some information across different pages. There are several options:

- Append the value to the URL and pass around;
- Store in cookie, which is small-size and may expire;
- Store in [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), which supports up to 5MB~10MB and lasts forever (if you do not clean it manually);
- Store in session, which goes away when session is destroyed.
- Store in database, like theme/skin.

Answer (score 0):

In the absolute plain *The Web* there is no persistence or memory. You make a request such as a `GET` for a page, the webserver responds by sending the page (and any referenced images, css, etc.) and you're done. Every request is independent of every other request.

Cookies are a way to maintain state between requests.  Cookies are used to maintain a *Session*, a concept that is not part of the basic web, or to maintain simpler bits of information. (There are other ways besides cookies, but that's another topic)

In your case, if you have users who login and have sessions you can store font size as some kind of preference that can be applied at sign-in.  If you don't (or even if you do) you can store the preferred size as a cookie value.

In either case you need some server-side processing beyond simple request/response to apply that preference, or some javascript in each page that would, for example, read the font size from the cookie and set it as a base `font-size` attribute on the `<body>` or some other appropriate element so all other sizes are adjusted accordingly — assuming you use relative font sizes using either percentages or *em*-s

If you have more information to store in addition to preferred font size then HTML 5 localStorage may be appropriate, but I'd say that is overkill if you only have this one preference.

In a system I have worked on, every page included "user.css" which was not an actual file; it was generated server-side when requested, based on a user's preferences stored in a database.

Without knowing more about your system it's difficult to be more specific.